# Android data usage listener

Tags: android

I am developing an application which sends some data to the server. I dont want my application to disturb other applications data transfer. I want to listen to the uplink status and check if its free before starting my transmission. I looked through the TrafficStats, ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo classes but could only find the data usage amount only. Is there any listener I can register to, to get the current uplink or downlink stats ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to listen to the uplink status and check if its free before starting my transmission.

There is no real concept of "free" here. You can use `TrafficStats` to measure bandwidth consumption over some brief period of time, to see if other apps are doing much at the moment.

> Is there any listener I can register to, to get the current uplink or downlink stats ?

No.

Comment: Hey,Thank you. I just wanted to be sure there weren't any API's for getting the status. Could you kindly tell me why you said "There is no real concept of "free" here." ? If none of the applications are transferring or receiving any data, then there isn't any ongoing transfer right ?

Comment: @user669444: "If none of the applications are transferring or receiving any data, then there isn't any ongoing transfer right?" -- correct. However, there is nothing in the OS that designates the Internet connection as being "free" as a distinct situation from "nobody happening to use it right this millisecond". Apps can use the Internet whenever they feel like it, assuming they have the `INTERNET` permission. All you can do is use `TrafficStats` to see if much is going on at the moment, and even that only tells you the current state, not the state in the future.